# Cannot get the :before element to appear on ReactiveForms input

Tags: css, forms, angular

I am trying to display a `FormControl` on a form to hold a telephone country code prefix, and I want it to always display a plus sign in the left-padding area. My bet was to use a `:before` element on the input, but surprisingly I cannot get it to appear in the DevTools inspector. When I started to notice the problem I even went despearate and tried to place the `:before` element on all inputs - to no avail. On the other hand, styles for the main input element work as expected.

Same goes with `:after`.

So my question is - does placing a `:before` or `:after` element work for anyone? Is it a know "feature" of ReactiveForms or a bug?

**css**

```
input[name="telCountryCode"]:before {
  content: '+';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

**ts**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  telCountryCode: '',
  telNumber: '',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

pseduo elements like :before/:after do not work on INPUT tag

Answer (score 1):

### :before/:after renders inside a container only

You can't use `:before/:after` or other pseudo-elements for `input`.
Also `img` `br` `hr` etc.

> It doesn't apply for self-closing elements.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the input with div

```
<div class="telCountryCode-wrapper">
<input type="text"  name="telCountryCode">
</div>
```

and use this css

```
.telCountryCode-wrapper{
position:relative;
}
.telCountryCode-wrapper:before{
 content: '+';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-elements can only be defined (or better said are only supported) on container elements. Because the way they are rendered are within the container itself as a child element.

> input can not contain other elements hence they're not supported.

Refer this [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)